# React with multiple pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm writing a React app with multiple pages. React is good for Single Page Applications. I've taken a look at React router and implemented them into my React app.

I find it difficult to pass data around between pages. Am I doing it wrong? Should I remove the existing components in my current page and add new components to "simulate" a page change?

Thank you.

Comment: what exactly you are looking for?How does a react router work?

Comment: I think you should take a look at http://redux.js.org/ if you have trouble with moving data around inside your react app

Comment: Seconded, redux is the gold standard for state management in pretty much any JS app

Comment: Thank u for ur replies. I am trying to update my store from my child component. My child component is unable to access my dispatch. I have a Home Component with a list of ToDos (I made use of map to render them). From ToDos, I want to dispatch actions to store the info upon selection. Pls advice thx.

Comment: use react-redux to bind your dispatch https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this with calling this.props.dispatch(MY_ACTION()) from my sub-component. Thank you everyone for ur response. :)